# How to authenticate OData service endpoint with Apache Olingo 4.4.x API Java Client Library?

Tags: apache, odata, olingo

I am using Apache Olingo Java Client API to call OData service endpoint, which requires an authentication.

I had tried following code on my environment :

```
URI absoluteUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceUrl).build();
client.getConfiguration().setHttpClientFactory(new BasicAuthHttpClientFactory("username", "passxxx"));

ODataEntitySetIteratorRequest<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> request = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getEntitySetIteratorRequest(absoluteUri);
request.setAccept("application/json;odata.metadata=none");
ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity>> response = request.execute();
```

when i execute my request it gives following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.serialization.JsonODataErrorDeserializer.doDeserialize(JsonODataErrorDeserializer.java:46)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.serialization.JsonDeserializer.toError(JsonDeserializer.java:442)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.serialization.ClientODataDeserializerImpl.toError(ClientODataDeserializerImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.serialization.ODataReaderImpl.readError(ODataReaderImpl.java:86)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.header.ODataErrorResponseChecker.checkResponse(ODataErrorResponseChecker.java:59)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractRequest.checkResponse(AbstractRequest.java:54)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataRequest.doExecute(AbstractODataRequest.java:310)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.execute(ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.execute(ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.java:36)
    at org.apache.olingo.samples.client.OlingoSampleApp.perform(OlingoSampleApp.java:131)
    at org.apache.olingo.samples.client.OlingoSampleApp.main(OlingoSampleApp.java:112)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataClientErrorException: (401) Unauthorized [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.header.ODataErrorResponseChecker.checkResponse(ODataErrorResponseChecker.java:76)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractRequest.checkResponse(AbstractRequest.java:54)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.AbstractODataRequest.doExecute(AbstractODataRequest.java:310)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.execute(ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.olingo.client.core.communication.request.retrieve.ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.execute(ODataEntitySetIteratorRequestImpl.java:36)
    at org.apache.olingo.samples.client.OlingoSampleApp.perform(OlingoSampleApp.java:131)
    at org.apache.olingo.samples.client.OlingoSampleApp.main(OlingoSampleApp.java:112)
```